# IIS Security - prevent web script to navigate upper level

Tags: security, iis

I would like to know how to prevent the web script to be able to navigate his upper level ? For instance, the web script is located at C:\Websites\Website-A and it shouldn't able to navigate to upper level or view other drive information.

My question is, what kind of security settings in order to prevent this case happens?

I have tried to set the user to the application pool at one of the application pools -> advanced settings -> Identity -> and set the user I have created. I did google for the solution but I can't find it (maybe I used the wrong keywords)

Could you give me some hints or solutions ?

Thank you in advanced.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is two-fold.

- Set the user for the application pool (as you mentioned). Make sure this is a limited user and does not have permissions to read or write outside of where is necessary (preferably read only if possible). Bottom line - **minimum required permissions**.
- You haven't said what your script does, but you should make sure that the code is not vulnerable to a [Directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack). If a user can pass strings such as `..\` as an input and the script blindly follows then it is vulnerable.